# Node.js sockets transport error. (GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4 404)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets

Following is my index.js file. The server connects like a charm. My APIs are working fine. I also tried to give a separate port to sockets but it shows the same error. The console keeps on printing this error.
(GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4 404)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const routes = require('./routes')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const helmet  = require("helmet");
const morgan  = require('morgan');
var fs        = require('file-system');
const Port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var moment    = require('moment')

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('./uploads'));

const connection = require('./connection');
connection();
app.use("/api", routes);

//-------------sockets--------------------------------------------------------------------

var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


  // On Connection
  io.on("connection", function (client) {
    console.log("Client connected...");
    client.on('room_join', function (msg) {
  
      if (msg.room_id != null && msg.room_id != '') {
        client.join(msg.room_id, () => {
          io.to(msg.room_id).emit('room_join_response', { status: true, room_id: msg.room_id, user_id: msg.user_id, business_id: msg.business_id });
        });
      } else {
        io.emit('room_join_response', { status: false, message: 'room id is missing!' });
      }
    });
    client.on('room_leave', (msg) => {
      try {
        console.log('room leave');
        client.leave();
        // io.server.leave();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });

app.listen(Port, () => {
   console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```